# Cadastro em mais de uma tabela com Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mvc

Então, eu tenho 3 tabelas(medicos, enderecos e telefones), primeiro eu faço a inserção na tabela medicos utilizando o método store que fica em seu próprio controller, e pego o id criado para ele e insiro nas outras tabelas juntamente com as outras informações. 
Para isso eu chamei as outras classes para dentro deste método, invés de utilizar os métodos delas.

O código a seguir está funcionando, mas gostaria de saber se este realmente é o melhor jeito de fazer isso. É correto fazer tudo somente no controller da classe medico e ignorar os metodos de inserção das outras classes? Não consegui pensar em algo que utilize o controller das três classes.

No utilizarei nenhum método das classes telefone e endereco, pois até mesmo na edição elas serão alteradas na classe medico. Não tem problema em excluir o controller delas e deixar somente a Model né?

PS: Alterei o código, agora está menor e mais limpo.

**Tabelas:**
medicos(id, nome, descricao, id_cidade); enderecos(id, rua, numero, sala, id_medico); telefones(id, id_medico, numero).
Um medico vai ter somente um endereco(rua, numero, etc..) , mas pode ter mais de um telefone.

MedicoController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();

    $medico = $this->medico->create($dataForm);

    $dataForm['id_medico'] = $medico->id;

    Endereco::create($dataForm);

    foreach($dataForm['fone'] as $fone)
    {
        $dataForm['fone'] = $fone;
        Telefone::create($dataForm);
    }
}
```

Model Medico

```
    namespace App\Models\painel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Medico extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'id_cidade', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

Model Endereco

```
    namespace App\Models\painel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Endereco extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'rua', 'numero', 'sala', 'id_medico'
    ];
}
```

Model Telefone

```
namespace App\Models\painel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Telefone extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'fone', 'id_medico'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Existe, se código pode ser melhorado, mas, coloque os 3 models e suas relações eu não estou entendendo elas

Comment: Alterei o post, agora talvez esteja mais fácil de entender. Basicamente a minha dúvida é q  como os dados vão estar em um mesmo form, eles vao ser enviados para um mesmo lugar(controller do medico), então a inserção das tres tabelas serão feitas em um mesmo método. Deixando de lado os métodos próprios das outras classes, isso é correto? Se sim, já q não usarei os métodos delas, posso excluir seus controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos iniciar a sua respostas pelos problemas, quando se utiliza o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) deve fazer as relações que [são explicadas pela documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) e são de grande valia não só no momento da recuperação, mas, também nas operações de criar, excluir e alterar. Em seu caso especifico me parece que as relações são as seguintes:

- *1* **Médico** *tem nenhum ou 1* **Endereco**, ***e***;
- *1* **Médico** *tem nenhum ou 1 ou mais* **Telefones**.

A primeira [relação seria 1 para 1 como descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) e a segunda [relação seria 1 para muitos também descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). O importante é que tenha em mente que isso é um prática normal e muito utilizada e o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) pode fazer tranquilamente esse processo de relacionamento, com as operações de `CRUD`.

Vou propor um exemplo minimo, mediante ao que eu vejo na sua pergunta e isso se aproxima do seu modelo real.

***Exemplo minimo:***

### Classes do Eloquent

***Medico***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Medico extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'medicos';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'id_cidade'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function endereco()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Endereco::class, 'id_medico','id');
    }

    public function telefones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class, 'id_medico', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

***Endereco***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Endereco extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_medico';
    protected $table = 'enderecos';
    protected $fillable = ['rua', 'numero', 'sala', 'id_medico'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function medico()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Peoples', 'id_medico', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

***Telefone***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Telefone extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'telefones';
    protected $fillable = ['fone', 'id_medico'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function medico()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Medico::class, 'id_medico', 'id');
    }
}
```

Observe que cada classe tem suas configurações claras porque, os seus campos não seguiram a nomenclatura padrão do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent), sem problemas, só que não seguindo a nomenclatura deve configurar manualmente os campos, tudo isso explicado [na documentação Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

O objetivo da pergunta é saber se os método pode ser simplificado e utilizando uma codificação mais limpa, e sim isso é possível, fixando os dados seria assim para gravar um médico com seu endereço e seus telefones:

### Operações:

```
//Criando Médico
$medico = Medico::create(['nome' => 'Medico A', 'id_cidade' => 1]);
if ($medico) {
    //Granvando Endereco;
    $medico->endereco()
           ->create([
               'rua' => 'Rua A',
               'numero' => 'Numero A',
               'sala' => 'Sala A'
           ]);
    //Gravando Telefones;
    $medico->telefones()->createMany([
        ['fone' => '1152526969'],
        ['fone' => '1169695252']
    ]);

    return $medico;
}
```

isso seria a gravação dos dados com dados fictícios e fixados no código, mas, pelo seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
$medico = Medico::create($request->all());
if ($medico) 
{    
    $medico->endereco()->create($request->all());
    foreach($request->only('fone')['fone'] as $f) 
    {
        $medico->telefones()->create(['fone' => $f]);
    }
    return $medico;
}
```

a diminuição de código, o padrão proposto pelas configurações de cada `Model Eloquent` e as facilidades do `framework Laravel` nos propõem a códigos bem limpos e de extrema capacidade de desenvolvimento.

***Observação:*** *na tabela de Medico tem uma relação com Cidades onde 1 médico pertence a uma Cidade o seu relacionamento inverso um Cidade pode ter vários médicos, é a mesma relação de Medico e Telefone se precisa configurar só seguir o mesmo exemplo.*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)
- [Eloquent: Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
- [Eloquent: One To One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
- [Eloquent: One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: A parte da inserção dos telefones funciona se eu deixo com os dados ficticios, mas não se eu deixo com os dados vindo do form. Não deveria deixar isso dentro de um foreach para percorrer todos numero? Meu input tá assim: <input type="text" name="fone[]">

Comment: Aparece o seguinte erro: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fone' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `telefones` (`id_convenio`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (14, 2017-07-03 20:45:48, 2017-07-03 20:45:48))

Comment: @DiegoVieira o erro é outro amigo, o erro é no nome do campo dá uma olhada nisso na base de dados e no seu código por favor?

Comment: Tá com o nome "fone" em todos lugares, tá certo colocar o name do input com colchete né?

Comment: @DiegoVieira eu já sei o porque deve ta vindo assim `fone[0] = "valor"`, `fone[1] = "valor"` é por isso. Dá um `var_dump($request->only('fone'))` e me fala o resultado não deve ta vindo chave e valor!

Comment: array(1) { ["fone"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "123" [1]=> string(3) "456" } }

Comment: @DiegoVieira olha lá o código... editei a resposta

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda!